# Signal R reconnect seems to create a new thread

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, signalr

We have a siglnalR hub hosted in IIS, and a WPF .net core application that connects. Everything is working perfectly on first run. However,  when IIS recycles the application pool, the WPF client re-reconnects successfully, but, (so it seems) on another thread, as when the user attempts to perform an action (open a new WPF window) -  the following error is thrown when creating a new instance of the window to open :-

```
"The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this"
```

This is how we connect to the hub :-

```
 private async void Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            _signalRConnection.On<Notification>(NotificationMessageStr, (message) =>
            {
                if (message != null && _signalRConnection != null)
                {
                    OnProcessMessage(message);
                }
            }
            );


            _signalRConnection.Reconnecting += error =>
            {
                OnReconnecting("Connection lost - Attempting to reconnect.");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };

            _signalRConnection.Reconnected += connectionId =>
            {
                OnReconnected("Reconnected");

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };

            _signalRConnection.Closed += error =>
            {
                OnLostConnection("Failed to connect");
                // Notify users the connection has been closed or manually try to restart the connection.

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
            try
        {
            //Connect to the server
            await _signalRConnection.StartAsync();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

When a message is received from the hub,  we call :-

```
 private void SubscriveToNewNotification()
        {
            vm.NewNotification += (sender, e) => { 
ShowNotificationAlert(e.NotificationMessage); };
        }


    private void ShowNotificationAlert(Notification notification) {
        NotificationAlert notificationAlert = new NotificationAlert();
        notificationAlert.notification = notification;
        notificationAlert.Show();
    }
```

And it is this:-

```
NotificationAlert notificationAlert = new NotificationAlert();
```

That is failing.

This is how the connection is built up :-

```
private void InitializeViewModel()
    {

        try
        {
string serviceAddress = "xxxx/notificationHub";


            connectHub = NotificationHubManager.CreateNotificationHub(serviceAddress, userInfo);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "--");
        }


        connectHub.ProcessMessage += (sender, e) =>
        {
         // THIS IS WHERE IT FALLS OVER
            NotificationAlert n = new NotificationAlert();
            OnNotificationReceived(e.NotificationMessage);
        };
```

-- This is the notification hub

```
 public static NotificationHubConnect CreateNotificationHub(string address, ISwiftUser userInfo = null)
    {
        HubConnection hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
           .WithUrl(address)
           .WithAutomaticReconnect()
           .Build();
        try
        {
            var result = new NotificationHubConnect(hubConnection, userInfo);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Is there a way to have the reconnect run on the same thread?

Comment: Please, share with us some code

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski sample code added to the post,  thank you

Comment: Is this .NET Core 3?

Comment: @Kiril1512  yes, this is .net core 3.  Ive tried that many variations, but still getting "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this"

Comment: Show how do you build your connection.

Comment: Why can't you just dispatcher.invokeasync back to the ui thread?

Comment: @Kiril1512 additional code added,  thank you

Comment: @Andy Thank you,  at what point would that be invoked? on the re-connet?

Comment: @Andy. this has resolved the issue,  thank you